# counting occurrence of consecutive elements in a list (python)

Tags: python, list

Given a list

```
a=['g','d','r','x','s','g','d','r']
```

I want to count for example the occurrence of gdr, so I would apply some function 
`a.function('g','d','r')` and return `2` to me (because gdr occurred 2 times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are *only* strings in the list, you can join them in a long string and use its `count` method:

```
>>> a=['g','d','r','x','s','g','d','r']
>>> ''.join(a).count('gdr')
2
```

If you have a mix of strings and numbers for example, you may use `map(str,a)` before joining and the method would still work:

```
>>> a=[1,13,4,2,1,13,4]
>>> ''.join(map(str,a)).count('1134')
2
```

If you need all this packed in a function, you can have something like this:

```
def count_pattern(lst, *pattern):
    return ''.join(l).count(''.join(pattern))
```

And will be able to call it: `count_pattern(a, 'g', 'd', 'r')` or `count_pattern(a, 'gdr')` or even `count_pattern(a, 'gd', 'r')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that as:

```
def get_occur(list, seq):
    return ''.join(list).count(''.join(seq))

>>> get_occur(['a', 's', 'a', 's'], ['a', 's'])
2
```

If you are passing in strings, you can do:

```
return your_string.count(pattern)
```

Comment: What if user passed `('gd', 'r')`?

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary, The OP stated that he is dealing with lists not strings.

Comment: You are missing the point, if OP is dealing with lists then why are you doing a sub-string search by joining list items? Your code and other answers as well will fail if OP wants to check `['as', 'a']` inside the list you used, I wonder if they want to check the items `['as', 'a']` or `'asa'` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
>>> a=['g','d','r','x','s','g','d','r']
>>> print "".join(a).count("gdr")
2
```